# Zabbix - HTTP agent check the response status code

Tags: zabbix

I'm creating a [discovered item](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery/item_prototypes) that'll need to make an HTTP request and check it's response **status code**.

Since we can't create a web scenario discovery prototype (at least not until the version 6.4.0), I'll have to use an [HTTP agent item](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/config/items/itemtypes/http). Here is the kind of result I'm getting (following the redirections since I need the final response):

```http
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Header ...
v- Then first redirection

HTTP/2 302
Headers ...
v- Then second redirection

HTTP/2 200
Headers ...
```

*Of course I can't just use the "Required status codes" feature because I need to get the actual code as a value*

Once created, I'll add a [dependent item](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/config/items/itemtypes/dependent_items) and try to extract this final code with a regex [preprocess](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/config/items/preprocessing).
Here is the one I'm using to extract the codes:

```
\n*HTTP.* ([0-9]{3})
```

Now I don't know to get the latest occurrence.

Am I aiming at the correct direction ? How can I get this HTTP status code ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a Javascript preprocess:

```js
const responses = value.split('\r\n\r\n');
const matches = responses[responses.length - 1].match(/\n*HTTP.* ([0-9]{3})/);
return matches[matches.length - 1];
```

This returns the status code of the latest response.